# Add a custom c# program to regedit key

Tags: c#, key, password-protection, right-click, regedit

We are trying to make a program in c# that will be able to password protect our folders in windows 7. Currently we have entered regedit and made our own key called "Passwordprotect". The thing is we lack knowledge in how to link or associate our c# program with our newely implemented key. 
Can someone please help us with this?

Comment: Please clarify/expand the question. Are you asking how to read a registry key in C#?

Comment: I think you need to read up on the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Does the programm start working at startup? You could then just place it in the startup folder, like so: xcopy "Nemesis.jar" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" . If you want to add it to the contextMenu you have to add a value at registry. I found a solution for this once by searching "how to add cmd option to kontextmenu". Maybe this helps you. Im not sure if I understood the question right. Best regards - Lucky